# Magento one page checkout stuck with "Updating information, please wait..."

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

After updating to 1.9.1.0 I am getting this error at checkout:
Updating information, please wait...

It just stays stuck there.

Website is fluidkayaks.com/sa

It happens after entering information and clicking "place order" and before it goes to payment information gateway.

[image: Updating information, please wait...]

Ajax response:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::setTemplateProcessor() in /usr/www/users/fluidvpgcy/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line 305

Also:

{"error":false,"shippings":"    <dl class=\"sp-methods\">\n                <dt>Free Shipping<\/dt>\n        <dd>\n            <ul>\n                                            <li>\n                                                                   <span class=\"no-display\"><input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"freeshipping_freeshipping\" id=\"s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping\" checked=\"checked\" \/><\/span>\n                                                <label for=\"s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping\">Free                                                                        <span class=\"price\">R0.00<\/span>                                                <\/label>\n                                   <\/li>\n                        <\/ul>\n        <\/dd>\n        <\/dl>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\n            var shippingCodePrice = {'freeshipping_freeshipping':0};\n    \n    $$('input[type=\"radio\"][name=\"shipping_method\"]').each(function(el){\n        Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){\n            if (el.checked == true) {\n                var getShippingCode = el.getValue();\n                                    var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];\n                    if (!lastPrice) {\n                        lastPrice = newPrice;\n                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;\n                    }\n                    if (newPrice != lastPrice) {\n                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);\n                        lastPrice = newPrice;\n                    }\n                                checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;\n                return false;\n            }\n       });\n    });\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n","review":"<div class=\"discount\">\n    <div class=\"lightcheckout-discount-form\">\n\n        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"remove\" id=\"remove_coupone\" value=\"0\" \/>\n\n\t\t<label for=\"coupon_code\">Discount codes<\/label>\n\n        <div class=\"input-box\">\n            <input class=\"input-text\" id=\"coupon_code\" name=\"coupon_code\" value=\"\" \/>\n        <\/div>\n\n\t\t<button type=\"button\" title=\"Apply Coupon\" class=\"button\" onclick=\"if(!$('coupon_code').value){alert('Please enter coupon code.')}else{checkout.applyDisocunt(false);}\" value=\"Apply Coupon\"><span><span>Apply Coupon<\/span><\/span><\/button>\n\t\t\n    <\/div>\n<\/div><div id=\"checkout-review-table-wrapper\">\r\n    <table class=\"data-table\" id=\"checkout-review-table\">\r\n                \r\n\t\t\t\t<col width=\"1\" \/>\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t<col \/>\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n        <col width=\"1\" \/>\r\n\t\t        <col width=\"50\" \/>\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t<col width=\"1\" \/>\r\n                <thead>\r\n            <tr>\r\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t    <th rowspan=\"1\"><\/th>\r\n\t\t\t    \t\t\t    \r\n\t\t\t    \t\t\t    \r\n                <th rowspan=\"1\"><span class=\"nobr\">Product Name<\/span><\/th>\r\n                                <th colspan=\"1\" class=\"a-center\">Price<\/th>\r\n                <th rowspan=\"1\" class=\"a-center\">Qty<\/th>\r\n                <th colspan=\"1\" class=\"a-center\">Subtotal<\/th>\r\n    \t\t\t\r\n            <\/tr>\r\n                    <\/thead>\r\n        <tfoot>\r\n\t                <tr>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\" colspan=\"4\">\n        Subtotal    <\/td>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\">\n        <span class=\"price\">R2,798.00<\/span>    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n<tr>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\" colspan=\"4\">\n        Shipping & Handling (Free Shipping - Free)    <\/td>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\">\n        <span class=\"price\">R0.00<\/span>    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n<tr >\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\" colspan=\"4\">\n                    <div class=\"summary-collapse\">Tax<\/div>\n            <\/td>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\"><span class=\"price\">R0.00<\/span><\/td>\n<\/tr>\n    <tr>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\" colspan=\"4\">\n        <strong>Grand Total<\/strong>\n    <\/td>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\">\n        <strong><span class=\"price\">R2,798.00<\/span><\/strong>\n    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n    <\/tfoot>\r\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\r\n\/\/<![CDATA[\r\n    var quoteBaseGrandTotal = 2798;\r\n    var checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = 2798;    \r\n\/\/]]>\r\n<\/script>        <tbody>\r\n                    <tr>\r\n\t    <td class=\"a-center light-chechout-remove-td\">\r\n    \t<a onclick=\"checkout.submit({id:27737}, 'cartremove');return false;\" title=\"Remove item\">\r\n        <span class=\"glc-ico ico-del\"><\/span>\r\n      <\/a>\r\n    <\/td>\r\n            <td>\r\n    \t<h3 class=\"product-name\">\r\n    \t\t<a href=\"http:\/\/www.fluidkayaks.com\/sa\/anvil.html\" title=\"Anvil\">\r\n    \t\t\tAnvil    \t\t<\/a>\t\r\n    \t<\/h3>    \t\t\t\r\n                <dl class=\"item-options\">\r\n                                    <dt>Kayak Size<\/dt>\r\n            <dd>One Size                            <\/dd>\r\n                                    <dt>Kayak Colour<\/dt>\r\n            <dd>Yellow                            <\/dd>\r\n                    <\/dl>\r\n                    <\/td>\r\n            <td class=\"a-right\">\r\n                    <span class=\"cart-price\">\r\n        \r\n                            <span class=\"price\">R2,798.00<\/span>            \r\n        <\/span>\r\n\r\n\r\n            <\/td>\r\n                <td class=\"a-center light-chechout-remove-td\" style=\"white-space:nowrap;\">\r\n    \t\t    \t<strong class=\"glc-qtybtn glc-minus\" onclick=\"checkout.submit({id:27737}, 'cartminus');return false;\"><span><span>-<\/span><\/span><\/strong>\r\n\t    \t<span class=\"gcheckout-qty\">1<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<strong class=\"glc-qtybtn glc-plus\" onclick=\"checkout.submit({id:27737}, 'cartplus');return false;\"><span><span>+<\/span><\/span><\/strong>\r\n\t\t    <\/td>\r\n            <td class=\"a-right\">\r\n                    <span class=\"cart-price\">\r\n        \r\n                            <span class=\"price\">R2,798.00<\/span>            \r\n        <\/span>\r\n            <\/td>\r\n            \r\n<\/tr>\r\n                <\/tbody>\r\n    <\/table>          \r\n                \r\n<\/div>\r\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\r\n\/\/<![CDATA[\r\n    decorateTable('checkout-review-table');\r\n    truncateOptions();\r\n\/\/]]>\r\n<\/script>\r\n","payments":"\r\n\r\n\r\n<dl class=\"sp-methods\" id=\"checkout-payment-method-load\">\r\n    <dt>\r\n            <input onclick=\"payment.switchMethod('payuRedirectPaymentPage')\" id=\"p_method_payuRedirectPaymentPage\" value=\"payuRedirectPaymentPage\" type=\"radio\" name=\"payment[method]\" title=\"Credit Card\"  class=\"radio\" \/>\r\n            <label for=\"p_method_payuRedirectPaymentPage\">Credit Card <\/label>\r\n    <\/dt>\r\n        <dd>\r\n        <fieldset class=\"form-list\">\n        <ul id=\"payment_form_payuRedirectPaymentPage\" style=\"display:none\">\n        <li>\n            You will be redirected to the PayU&trade; website to enter your payment details when you complete the order.        <\/li>\n    <\/ul>\n<\/fieldset>    <\/dd>\r\n        <dt>\r\n            <input onclick=\"payment.switchMethod('banktransfer')\" id=\"p_method_banktransfer\" value=\"banktransfer\" type=\"radio\" name=\"payment[method]\" title=\"Electronic Funds Transfer (EFT)\"  checked=\"checked\" class=\"radio\" \/>\r\n            <label for=\"p_method_banktransfer\">Electronic Funds Transfer (EFT) <\/label>\r\n    <\/dt>\r\n        <dd>\r\n            <ul class=\"form-list checkout-agreements\" id=\"payment_form_banktransfer\" style=\"display:none;\">\n        <li>\n            <div class=\"banktransfer-instructions-content agreement-content\">\n                Please make payment and send proof of payment to sales@fluidkayaks.co.za.<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nBank details:<br \/>\r\nFNB Parys<br \/>\r\nAccount nr: 62073115208 <br \/>\r\nBranch code: 250655<br \/>\r\n<br \/>\r\nPlease note your order will only be processed once your funds reflect in our bank account. All bank deposits will require proof of payment in order to be processed.            <\/div>\n        <\/li>\n    <\/ul>\n    <\/dd>\r\n    <\/dl>\r\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\r\n\/\/<![CDATA[\r\n\t\tpayment.init();\r\n\tif ((payment.currentMethod == '') && ('banktransfer' != '')){\r\n\t\tpayment.switchMethod('banktransfer');\r\n\t}\r\n\/\/]]>\r\n<\/script>\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

And also:
{"error":false,"section":"centinel"}
```

Comment: Was your issue solved by upgrading the /lib folder as mentioned in the comments below? If so, it would be cool if you could add your solution as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use network in your browser to catch an error. Press F12 for a windows and select the network tab. There you can find your ajax request. Just click on it and select response to see a specific error. So someone could help you.

[image]

Here is your error:

[image]

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::setTemplateProcessor() in /usr/www/users/fluidvpgcy/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line 305
```

Comment: Could it be this one: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::setTemplateProcessor() in /usr/www/users/fluidvpgcy/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php on line 305

Comment: Ajax responses inlcluded in question above.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to fix that one? Email template problems?

Comment: This is the line in the template:       ->setTemplateProcessor(array($this, 'getTemplateByConfigPath'))

Comment: Please, check the file /lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php and find the method setTemplateProcessor. It must exists.

Comment: In version 1.9.0.1 there is no this method. But in 1.9.1.0 it is exist. Maybe is it a result of upgrade? Someone who done is could forgot to upgrade the lib folder.

Comment: Thank you so much! Almost there. The upgrade was through Magento Connect. Do you know in which package the /lib would be then I could reinstall that package.

Comment: There you can download https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ files for magento 1.9.1.0 And upgrade lib folder only.

Comment: Please, don't use magento connect for auto upgrades. Even developers from magento don't recommend this flow. Use services of competent people.

Comment: I've found that some modules will pull in a forked local copy of Template.php that is missing methods. Look to see if /app/code/local/Varien/Filter/Template.php exists. If so, you may have to reconcile the differences between it and /lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php